# How to populate an array with a certain size into another one with a bigger size on c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, populate

I am trying to populate an array of angles into another one with more elements :

```
uint16_t _sector[SECTORS_MAX] = {0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315};
```

The idea is, I have another array with 72 elements compared to this one above with only 8, each angle up there represents a sector and so the 72 element array is going to have 9 angles per sector instead of one, where each 9 angles represent a sector. How do I make a loop that manages to do that?

Comment: "*How do I make a loop that manages to do that?*" - do *what* exactly? What do you want to achieve? You explained your data structure and then ask how to *manage to do that*, but still, have not provided the actual task. Please elaborate

Comment: Why not just use a `std::vector`?

Comment: In default I have one array that consumes 8 angles which represent 8 different sectors of a distance sensor, each angle is the center angle of a center with a width of 45 degrees, I want to use another driver for this sensor in which the total number of sectors is 72, so 72 angles that represent the middle of it. But I still dont want to expand the existing array as I want to arrange 72 sectors in a matter where the first 9 belong to sector number 1 of the original array which is 0 and so on.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are asking. Could you somehow make it more clear? How do you want to compare?

Comment: I am confused. So you want an array that has elements incremented by the value of `360/72 = 5` ? Is `std::vector<int> v(72); std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0); std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), [](int i) { return i * 5; });` sufficient?

Comment: Right now I have an array with these elements here {0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315} which are angles and sectors which correspond to the angles from sector 0, I want to loop through an array that has elements incremented by the value of 5 as @KamilCuk mentioned and assign both

Answer (score 3):

Since you have 9 angles per sector you need to `#define ANGLES_MAX` as well:

```
#define SECTORS_MAX 8
#define ANGLES_MAX 9
```

You would then need to use a two dimensional array to store the angles:

```
uint16_t SectorAngles[SECTORS_MAX][ANGLES_MAX];
```

Let's say that the name of the array which contains the 72 angles is `TotalAngles`
It would have been defined something like this:

```
uint16_t TotalAngles[72];
```

Now you can copy the angles from  `TotalAngles` to `SectorAngles` like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SECTORS_MAX; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < ANGLES_MAX; j++)
    {
        SectorAngles[i][j] = TotalAngles[i*8 + j];
    }
}
```

Comment: "you need to #define ANGLES_MAX" - *Please* don't use preprocessor macros when you can use a proper `const` or `constexpr` *variable*. `#define` is, more often than not, a huge code smell in modern C++.